# Get atoms of a Boolean formula in Z3

Tags: z3, z3py

I was wondering if there is a method to get the atoms of a Boolean formula:

```
a = Bool('a')
b = Bool('b')
c = Bool('C')
d = Bool('D')
e = Bool('E')
f = Bool('F')

formula = And(Or(a, b), Or(c, d), Or(e, f))
```

I wonder if something like this exists:

```
formula.get_atoms() or get_atoms(formula)
```

to give me following desired output:

```
{A, B, C, D, E, F}
```

In `pySMT`, `get_atoms()` exists the provides the atoms. However, for some reason, I need to experiment on `Z3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse through the hierarchy of `children()` ([documentation](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3py_1_1_expr_ref.html#a6b3e33bf411fb3403b26a02ec6ad93d4)):

```
def atoms(expr):
    a = set()
    if not str(expr) in {'True', 'False'}:
        c = expr.children()
        if len(c):
            for child in c:
                a = a.union(atoms(child))  
        else:
            a = {expr}
    return a    

a = Bool('a')
b = Bool('b')
c = Bool('C')
d = Bool('D')
e = Bool('E')
f = Bool('F')

formula = And(Or(a, b), Or(c, d), Or(e, f))

print(atoms(formula))
```

Comment: Note that this will also return constant values. (Try it on `Or(True, a)` for instance.) The OP probably didn't want that, but perhaps it's not a big deal.